# TeX to image over command line

Tags: conversion, mac

I'd like to generate an image with math formulas with TeX from command line. Something like:

```
$ tex-executable "E=\frac{m_1v^2}{2}" e2.png
```

I have MacTex 2009 installed and I'm pretty sure that something like that already exists in this distribution. If not please suggest me a tool.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938693/tex-to-image-over-command-line?noredirect=1). Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 34):

### Update: 2012-01:

The `standalone` class now has a `varwidth` option, so with the current release, one would simply use the `[varwidth]` package option:

```
\ifdefined\formula
\else
    \def\formula{E = m c^2}
\fi
\documentclass[border=2pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ \formula \]
\end{document}
```

---

Save the following as `formula.tex`:

```
\ifdefined\formula
\else
    \def\formula{E = m c^2}
\fi
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\[ \formula \]
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

[The `standalone` class](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/standalone) is used for cropping. [The `varwidth` environment](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/varwidth) is similar to the `minipage` environment, but sets its width to match the *narrower natural width* based on the content.

The `ifdefined...\fi` is only necessary so that this file can be compiled by itself, which is useful to test to ensure that there are no errors in it, in case you decide to make changes to it.

Then you can process this file as:

```
pdflatex "\def\formula{E=\frac{m_1v^2}{2}}\input{formula.tex}"
convert -density 300 formula.pdf -quality 90 formula.png
```

where `convert` is part of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org).  This yields the following PNG file:

[image]

I have not used it, but the [current development version of `standalone`](http://latex.scharrer-online.de/general/browser/standalone/dev) can generate the PNG directly if you use

```
\documentclass[convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
```

Alternatively you could also use `GIMP`as per [this link from Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Export_To_Other_Formats#PNG).

Comment: when using `standalone` for direct png production, `-shell-escape` option must be supplied to the `pdflatex` command.

Answer (score 11):

There are a few tools called `tex2png`. You should be able to use one of them for this purpose:

- [`tex2png`](http://xyne.archlinux.ca/projects/tex2png/) (from Arch Linux)
- [`tex2png`](http://www.nawouak.net/?cat=informatics.tex2png+lang=en) (by Bruno Bachelet)

Answer (score 8):

If you run into portability issues and require an online version, you could always use the [Online LaTeX Equation Editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php). It allows for exporting equations (display or inline) in a variety of formats and resolutions:

- `.gif`
- `.png`
- `.pdf`
- `.swf`
- `.emf`
- `.svg`

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers above satisfied me, so I wrote [pnglatex](https://github.com/mneri/pnglatex). It works on Linux and internally uses `latex` and `dvipng` programs. It is as easy as:

```
./pnglatex -f "(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab"
```

Other options are `-b <color>` to change background color (valid colors are `White`, `Emerald`, `Transparent`, ...); `-d` for display math environment; `-o <output-file-name>` to specify the name of the output image; `-p <package1:package2:...:packagen>` to use LaTeX packages (packages are separated by colons); `-s <font-size>` to set the font size.

A complex example could be

```
./pnglatex -b Transparent -d -p amsmath -o ~/formula.png -s 10 -f "\mathit{ws}_i\cap\mathit{ws}_j\neq\emptyset"
```

Since it is a script remember to set the execution bits before use, as in:

```
sudo chmod +x pnglatex
```

Comment: nice, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

As you have explicitly asked for a command-line solution this is basically a non-answer. However, with respect to others looking for a "how to quickly get a PNG out of a LaTeX equation" solution it belongs here:

For Mac OSX there is the LaTeXit [LaTeXit tool](http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/latexit.php), which provides quick typesetting, a history (very useful for later edits) and lets you copy the result in various formats (including PNG) into the clipboard.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the question it appears that the wanted end result would be a PNG raster image.

To that end, Mac OS X command `sips` (Scriptable Image Processing System) can be of help in converting the XeTeX (or, `xdvipdfmx`) generated PDF file into a PNG file. `sips` comes with OS X so you don't need to install anything extra. Because of formatting concerns in this here webpage, I'll use a shell heredoc, but it could be just as well all be on the same line:

```
xetex <<EOF
\advance\hoffset by-1in % default is one inch away, so remove that
\advance\voffset by-1in % ditto
\setbox0\hbox{$\displaystyle % set into a box so we can measure its dimensions
E={m_lv^2\over2} % <<< your equation here
$}
\special{papersize=\the\wd0,\the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0} % set the papersize to the box size
\box0 % actually typeset the box
\bye
EOF
sips -s format png texput.pdf --out texput.png
```

Or as a one-liner, this time outputting a JPG file (you will need to remove the line-breaks manually):

```
xetex '\advance\hoffset by-1in\advance\voffset by-1in\setbox0
       \hbox{$\displaystyle E={m_1v^2\over2}$}\special{papersize=\the\wd0,
       \the\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0}\box0\bye' && 
       sips -s format jpeg texput.pdf --out texput.jpg
```

As Peter mentions in a comment, both of the above will crop the resulting PDF file (but not the PNG file), so if you need the PDF file as well, you could change the `\voffset` reduction to `-.99in` and add to the papersize height calculation a `+.01in`.

Comment: In the PDF version I notice that the formula is cut off (Also, you missed the `=`).

Comment: @Peter: Welp, I see no cut off in the png, but thanks for the missing `=`

Comment: Problem is in the PDF (not png).  Also as it is now formatted it is "cut-and-pastable" into a Unix shell.