# Reduce vertical space between text and table and remove table indentation

Tags: tables, spacing

I want to reduce the vertical space between the first line text and the start of the table.

I also want to remove the indent on the table, so that all three lines start at exactly the same vertical point.

```
\documentclass[final,a4paper,notitlepage,10pt]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % inputenc for encoding to utf8

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   % this page does not have a header

Testing some text on the first line.\\
\begin{tabular}{l l}\\
Lorem ipsum & dolor sit amet
\end{tabular}\\
Why was the table above indented? and how can I reduce the space between first line and start of the table?

\end{document}
```

I couldn't find any table indent command that I could simply reduce to 0. I am open to using a different tabular environment if it gets the job done easily.

This currently gives something similar to:

[image: Table vertical space and indent MWE]

Comment: Also how can I easily upload a picture of just the surrounding text instead of a full page pdf image?

Comment: I usually generate a PNG when uploading pictures.

Comment: Using dvipng or similar after you compile to dvi?

Comment: I personally just capture the image form the screen on a Mac, but see this on [how to convert TeX to image over command line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/tex-to-image-over-command-line/34058#34058)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I eliminated the `\\` and replaced it with a blank line as it is a new paragraph. The `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` eliminates the space between the first line and the table. You can replace the size with some other value to adjust the vertical spacing, for example `\vspace*{-5mm}`.

Also, use `@{}` to eliminate the the column spacing on the left hand side.

[image]

The `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` was used to show the margins.

```
\documentclass[final,a4paper,notitlepage,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % inputenc for encoding to utf8

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   % this page does not have a header

Testing some text on the first line.

\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l l}\\
Lorem ipsum & dolor sit amet
\end{tabular}\\
Why was the table above indented? and how can I reduce the space between first line and start of the table?
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect that worked, thanks! Is \par generally better to use rather than \\?

Comment: My preference is usually to leave a blank line (I will adjust this example). I think a blank line is easier to read than a `\\ `

Comment: `\vspace{-5cm}` or muliple of `\baselineskip` is a manipulation. There should be some logical way...

Comment: How can I do this for an itemize. I mean reduce spaces between bullet points

Comment: @41041729: That is totally unrelated to this question and I suggest you ask a _new_ question so that you (and others) can find it in the future.

Comment: Okay @Peter Grill