# Remove heading of multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn, white-space

I am trying to learn Latex and it is really driving me nuts...

I would like to remove any unecessary whitespace when using multicolumn (whitespace before, and the heading which i don't need in this case)
Here is an example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Hi}
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\% i removed the heading but it creates unecessary whitespace
    X&X&X\\
    X&X&X\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How to make the "Hi"as close as possible to the row with the X's? I am having a very hard time figuring it out..Please help!
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/53787) The most obvious thing I can suggest: comment the multicolumn entirely (provided you don't really need it).

Comment: Never mind - tested it and the whitespace is still there. Let me check another way...

Comment: How? I obviously already tried to remove the empty {} for the heading but all it does is to take the first "X" as a heading

Comment: No worries - I was referring to something like this: `% \multicolumn{...}`. But I have tested it, and it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: No problem, any other suggestion?

Comment: Try putting `\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` before the `\begin{table}`, as per [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46147/53787). If it works for you, I can put it as an answer.

Comment: correct syntax of the firs line of the your table is: `\multicolumn{2}{c}{} &  `. since this row is empty, just remove it.

Comment: It removes the whitespace just before the tabular but not the heading of the multi-column,

Comment: @Zarko as i said before all it does is to take the first "X" as a heading

Comment: your approach and expectation are wrong. (i) floats -- in your case `table` always (deliberately) add some vertical space before and after float content. remove this space is against nice typography provided by `latex`(ii) have a label in float without `caption` is nonsense, since label not referee float but caption (which is missing), (iii) it is not clear what you mean with `heading`. if you mean caption of table? then put`\caption{ ... table title ...}`  before `tabular`, (iv) etc. you should clarify what is your problem.

Comment: @Zarko why commands like \parskip and \vspace then exists? I think you're a big fan of latex which i understands it's beautiful but what you don't understand is first i am newbie and second it should have the possibility to change things like that, even if you think it is already good enough. I don't understand why you think it is nonsense to want to draw multi columns without any caption? i always did that irl why wouldn't it be possible in latex?

Comment: @JihaneSbaytti, mentioned command has own purposes (`\parskip` for global settings of vertical space between paragraphs, `\vspace` mostly for defining vertical spaces at defining of new environments and rarely for what you insinuate). if the context of your problem be clear to me, i would glad to help you. caption: it is nonsense has label in float without caption. you can have table without caption, but what you will do if the table will float on the next page? As novice i suggest to read some introduction information about `latex`, for example https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you need no floating table you can omit environment `table` (but then you also loose the floating possibility) in your code to make the "Hi" as close as possible to the row with the X's.

For a better typography environment `table` adds space before and after an floating table.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\textsc{Hi}

%\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
%   \multicolumn{2}{c}{title}\\% i removed the heading but it creates unecessary whitespace
    X&X&X\\
    X&X&X\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:multicol}
%\end{table}

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

From a typographical view I do **not** recommend it ...

**EDIT:**

I recommend to use environment `table`.  Please test the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{blindtext} % to create dummy text

\begin{document}

\blindtext % to create a short dummy text
\textsc{Hi}

%\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
%   \multicolumn{2}{c}{title}\\% i removed the heading but it creates unecessary whitespace
    X&X&X\\
    X&X&X\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:multicol}
%\end{table}

\blindtext % to create a short dummy text

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    X&X&X\\
    X&X&X\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image]

Comment: Wow ok i didn't think it would be that simple, thanks a lot!!

Comment: What do you recommand then?

Comment: @Zarko thank you for reminding me I just started to learn Latex, and  for pointing out two mistakes in my code.  if for you i am on a "very wrong way" because i did use \textsc instead of \lipsum[1] just for the purpose of the example and knowing i am a beginner, i really don't think so and thanks for the good welcoming here!

Comment: sorry, you not catch the point. i'm not offend you, contrary, so no place for sarcasm here.