# Remove Vertical Space on Page

Tags: vertical-spacing

I am trying to remove blank vertical space on a page.
I tried this solution ([Reduce vertical space between text and table and remove table indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46146/reduce-vertical-space-between-text-and-table-and-remove-table-indentation)) but it didn't work.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Securities Activities Licensed}
The Capital Market Law provides a mechanism for licensing the following activities
\begin{enumerate}
\item advising; 
\item arranging; 
\item managing; and 
\item custody
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{-1cm}
\begin{table}
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Activity/\\ Type of Company
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}




\end{document}
```

As to the second point, I'm not sure \tablularx is the solution:

[image: table]

using this code (after adding tabularx package in the preamble:

```
    \begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|X|X|}

    \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Activity/\\ Type of Company\end{tabular}                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Custody} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Dealing} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Managing} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Arranging/Advising} \\ 
    \hline
Joint Stock Company                                                                                                      & X                            & X                            & X                             & X                                       \\ \hline
Local Bank Subsidiary                                                                                                    & X                            & X                            & X                             & X                                       \\ \hline
Saudi Joint Stock Company                                                                                                & X                            & X                            & X                             & X                                       \\ \hline
    \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Subsidiary of foreign financial institution licensed\\ under Banking Control law\end{tabular} & X                            & X                            & X                             & X                                       \\ 
    \hline
Any other legal entity                                                                                                   &                              &                              &                               & X                                       \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: Use `\begin{table}[ht!]` (`\vspace{-1cm}` is not necessary).

Comment: Make this as an answer and I'll mark it solved, But I don't know *why* \vspace doesn't work, nor the meaning of the [h!] option. I'd like to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table environment is a `float` and its place will be chosen by LaTeX. You can *suggest* to LaTeX the place you want using  optionals parameters like `h` (here), `t` (top), `b` (bottom). The `!` makes LateX ignore other restrictions like the number of floats on the page, etc.  Their order does not matter.

See [fine tune the placement of tables and figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8653/161015) for a short explanation and/or  [the full history on floats placement](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/161015) for a complete one.

So by being a float the `\vspace` after the items will not have any effect whatsoever over its final position.

Not related with your question.

The problem with `resizebox` is that it changes font sizes.

If you want a table that uses the full line width, one possibility is the `tabularx` package. The X columns will accommodate their width to achieve that.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tabularx} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered X column

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Securities Activities Licensed}
    The Capital Market Law provides a mechanism for licensing the following activities
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item advising; 
        \item arranging; 
        \item managing; and 
        \item custody
    \end{enumerate}
    
    \begin{table}[!ht]
        \centering
        \caption{Using \texttt{tabularx}}
            \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|X|X|X|}
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}{l}
                    Activity/\\ Type of Company
                \end{tabular}  & zz & zz & zz \\ \hline         
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
    
        \begin{table}[!ht]
        \centering
        \caption{Using \texttt{tabularx} and centered columns}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|Y|Y|Y|Y|}
            \hline
            \begin{tabular}{>{\Large\bfseries}l}
                Activity/\\ Type of Company
            \end{tabular}  & zz & zz & zz \\ \hline         
        \end{tabularx}

    \end{table}
    
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Using \texttt{resizebox} changes the font size}
        \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
            \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Activity/\\ Type of Company
                \end{tabular} 
        \end{tabular}}
    \end{table} 
    
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** after follow up question.

[image: b]

Try this code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=3.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=4.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} % centered X column

\begin{document}
    
     \begin{table}[ht!]
        \centering
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{4pt}% extra row separation <<<%
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|Y|Y|Y|Y|}                       
            \hline
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l}Activity/\\ Type of Company\end{tabular}   & Custody & Dealing & Managing 
            &\begin{tabular}{c} Arranging/ \\ Advising\end{tabular} \\ \hline   
            Joint Stock Company                 & X & X & X & X     \\ \hline
            Local Bank Subsidiary               & X & X & X & X     \\ \hline
            Saudi Joint Stock Company           & X & X & X & X     \\ \hline
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Subsidiary of foreign \\ financial institution licensed\\ under Banking Control law\end{tabular}
                                                & X & X & X & X     \\ \hline
            Any other legal entity              &   &   &   & X     \\ \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure tabularx is the solution, the table still runs off the page. I can't post images here, I have to link to them: https://imgur.com/a/IK5d8Nd

Comment: @user26732  I added an update to the answer, now it deals with `tabularx`.