# Script for LaTeX formula to image conversion

Tags: linux, png

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TeX to image over command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/tex-to-image-over-command-line)

Is there a script for converting LaTeX math formulae (not document) to PNG, GIF or JPEG?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [TeX to image over command line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34058/4301)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [TeX to GIF or PNG](http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/textogif/) for this.

Answer (score 2):

I really like [Tex2im](http://www.nought.de/tex2im.php) because:

1. It's a simple bash script
2. It doesn't require a document wrapper or `\begin{equation}`
3. It supports stuff other than formulae (see the -n argument)
4. It's easy to customize text and background colors, or to get a transparent background
5. Your preferred default values can be set in a `.tex2imrc` file

It requires a working LaTeX installation and ImageMagick.