# Generate an image with minimum space around it

Tags: spacing, standalone

I'm using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34058/35603) to generate images:

```tex
\ifdefined\formula
\else
\def\formula{E = m c^2}
\fi
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\[ \formula \]
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

Everything works perfect when I have a large multi-level formula, say something like this `pV=\frac{m}{M}RT`.

However, when the formula gets more flat, like `p=mv`, I get extra space at the top. Looks like the document has some kind of a min height … How do I remove it? So that the resulting img/pdf will be exactly the size of my formula + border?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The space comes from `\baselineskip`, inserted by the displayed equation.

The following example does not use `\[`...`\]`, but simulates it via inline math and setting `\displaystyle`:

```
\ifdefined\formula
\else
\def\formula{p=mv}
\fi
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\begin{document}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
$\displaystyle\formula$%
\end{varwidth}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]