# How to convert Latex code to generate equations in Powerpoint?

Tags: math-mode

I have exported my `maple` mathematical matrices to `latex` and now I want to show those equations in Powerpoint presentation. I have installed `MathType` in `MS Powerpoint` that converts basic latex codes or equation to mathtype but not the matrices. For example If if paste below code into Mathtype it gives error;

```
 Error: This equation has exceeded the maximum width and/or height allowed. Remember mathtype is not a word processor.
```

Latex Code that I want to convert to Mathtype:

```
\begin{equation}
T_{R,A_1}= \left[\begin {array}{cccc} \cos  \psi_{{1}}  \cos  \delta_{{1}}  &-\sin 
\psi_{{1}}  &\sin \ \delta_{{1}}  \cos  \psi_{{1}}  &-\sin  \delta_{{1}}  \cos  
\psi_{{1}}  r-\sin  \psi_{{1}}  {\it k5}+{\it k2}\\ \noalign{\medskip}\cos  \beta  
\sin  \psi_{{1}}  \cos  \delta_{{1}}  +\sin  \beta  \sin  \delta_{{1}}  &\cos  \beta  
\cos  \psi_{{1}}  &\cos  \beta  \sin  \delta_{{1}}  \sin  \psi_{{1}}  -\sin  \beta  
\cos  \delta_{{1}}  & T_2\\ \noalign{\medskip}\sin  \beta  \sin  \psi_{{1}}  \cos  
\delta_{{1}}  -\cos  \beta  \sin  \delta_{{1}}  &\sin  \beta  \cos  \psi_{{1}}  
&\sin  \beta  \sin  \delta_{{1}}  \sin \psi_{{1}}  +\cos  \beta  \cos  \delta_{{1}}  
& T_1 \\ \noalign{\medskip}0&0&0&1\end {array}\right]

\end{equation}
```

Comment: I would recommend you [convert TeX to image over command line](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34054/tex-to-image-over-command-line) and insert the image into Powerpoint.

Comment: @PeterGrill what do you mean by over command line? I exported maple directly to images but that was low quality. I need high quality

Comment: The link I provided should explain how to obtain an image from TeX code.  The quality of the image can be controlled via TeX, don't know about Maple.

Comment: @wafeeq Is there any chance you can use [beamer](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) instead of MS Powerpoint? That would make easier to directly use the LaTeX codes.

Comment: Also, this equation is rather wide and will not display very well even in TeX without some reorganization.

Comment: Is there any doc for re arrangement of such big equations or matrices for report writing? could you suggest some links?

Comment: @PeterGrill I tried to used command line method you suggested. It converts the file to pdf and when I run `convert -density 600x600 file.pdf -quality 90 -resize 1080x800 file.png` it gives error that `unknown command -600x600`

Comment: @MMA Yes this is possibility but I have to design a proper format that needs some designing as in Power point its working for all others so its more convenient. In future I am also thinking to move on completely latex. good idea thanks