# Get image of equation

Tags: graphics, pdftex, convert

I would like to make `.png` images of equations. To achive that I use
`pdflatex` + `pdfcrop` + `convert`. But it takes more than 3 seconds on my computer to process simple $$E=mc^2$$. But I will generate dozens of images and I would like to do it as fast as possible.

`pdfcrop` is really slow and now I am trying to fit equation into page to except crop from my cycle.
I use this:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{equation*}
\resizebox{1.0\linewidth}{!} 
{
    $ E = mc^2 $
}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

`pdflatex` produces this:
[image: 1]

So, it's a lot of blank space around the equation. Moreover, I would like to use `latex` instead of `pdflatex` because it's faster. But `latex` ignores `resizebox` environment. So, my questions are: Is it possible to

1) Make `pdflatex` scale equation to entire page?

2) Similar but using `latex`?

3) Or maybe there is another way to produce images of equations?

Comment: Latex is not really faster than pdflatex, remember it is the same executable. See the standalone class, it is build for stuff like this. Ive used it to make equation images for someone to use in InDesign

Comment: @daleif can you please provide an example of generating image using standalone?

Comment: @danielleontiev: Generating image using standalone is addressed in [TeX to image over command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34054/4301).  I think a lot of the time is taken in loading tex. This can be sped using a `.fmt` file as per [Custom format file: How to automate the generation of the “precompiled preamble” whenever one of the files that are used there are changed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/49388/4301) and [Ultrafast PDFLaTeX with precompiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79493/4301).

Comment: Get rid of the resize box, and the thispagestyle, replace report by standalone

Comment: But why are you doing this? To put in a word document or is it for other use?

Comment: @ArneTimperman it's for external use

Comment: Using `TeX4ht`, you can generate `PNG` format file for all display equations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sometimes also need a picture of a LaTeX equation. For this, I use the following tex file `equation.tex`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle  E = m\,c^2$
\end{document}
```

Since it uses the `standalone` class, no `pdfcrop` is required and the resulting PDF contains your equation only, and nothing else, no borders, nothing. In the same folder as the `equation.tex` I also have a `Makefile` as follows

```
.PHONY: all clean

equation.pdf: equation.tex
    pdflatex --interaction=nonstopmode equation.tex
    convert -background white -alpha remove -density 600 equation.pdf equation.png

clean:
    --@rm -rf *.aux *.log *.lof *.bak *.loa *.log *.lot *.bbl
    --@rm -rf *.blg *.dvi *.out *.brf *.thm *.toc *.idx *.ilg *.ind
    --@rm -rf *eps-converted-to.pdf *.gnuplot *.tps
    --@rm -rf *.nav *.snm *.vrb *.lol *.tmp *.synctex *.synctex.gz
    --@rm -rf *.xwm *.pdf
```

and if you run the `make` command inside this directory, it produces the PDF with the equation and converts it to PNG. Note that on Windows, you need to enter the full path to the `convert` tool, e.g.

```
c:\programs\ImageMagick-6.8.5\bin\convert -background white -alpha remove -density 600 equation.pdf equation.png
```

On my box, this PDF creation and the conversion to PDF runs pretty fast. I would say less than 1/2 sec, and not 3 sec.

The above shown mwe produces this png file:

[image: equation]

Answer (score 0):

If you use TeXstudio, it has the function "preview selection".
You can just select an equation and use the function.

[image]

[image]